# Created database but table can't be found Android SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

Iv'e created android SQLite database, but couldn't find the table that was created.
Following is my implemented code. What seems to be the problem review and give feedback.

```
public static final int Database_version = 2
private static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES =
        "CREATE TABLE " + TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                TableData.TableInfo.USER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                TableData.TableInfo.USER_PASS +" TEXT "+ "," +
                TableData.TableInfo.USER_EMAIL +" TEXT "+ ")";

public DatabaseOperations(Context context) {
    super(context, TableData.TableInfo.DATABASE_NAME, null, Database_version);
    Log.d("Tag", "Database created");
};
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sdb) {
    sdb.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES);
    Log.d("Tag", "Table created");

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

public void putInformation(DatabaseOperations drop, String name, String pass, String email) {
    SQLiteDatabase SQ = drop.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.USER_ID, name);
    cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.USER_PASS, pass);
    cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.USER_EMAIL, email);
    long k = SQ.insert(TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
    Log.d("Tag", "inert a row");
}

public Cursor getInformation(DatabaseOperations dop) {
    SQLiteDatabase SQ = dop.getReadableDatabase();
    String[] coloumns = {TableData.TableInfo.USER_ID, TableData.TableInfo.USER_PASS, TableData.TableInfo.USER_EMAIL};
    Cursor CR = SQ.query(TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_NAME, coloumns, null, null, null, null, null);
    return CR;
}
}
```

Comment: follow this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you've missed a semicolon inside the quotes at the end (after the close parenthesis). Edit: Also there's a space before the open parenthesis.  I don't think that should be there.  There's no space after the comma after "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY".  There's a space between "TEXT" and the comma for "USER_PASS".  Last, I don't think you need the last space after "TEXT" for "USER_EMAIL".

There's a lot going on in creating a database and SQLite has no tolerance for typos (and doesn't give much indication of what it doesn't like).  I hope I've found all the typos in this.  Here's some code to try (and hopefully I didn't add my own typos).

```
public static final int Database_version = 2 
private static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES = "CREATE TABLE " +
        TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_NAME +
        "(" +
        TableData.TableInfo.USER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
        TableData.TableInfo.USER_PASS + " TEXT, "+
        TableData.TableInfo.USER_EMAIL + " TEXT"+
        ");";
```

Comment: I've made a few more changes.  Try those to see if they work for you.